# How can I make the function repeat?

Tags: python, function, repeat

How can I make the function repeat if the answer is wrong, so the program chooses a new number.

Making a while loop

```
import random, sys

def randomNumber(diceRoll):

    while True:
        print('Pick a number 1 to 6')
        userEntry = int(input())

        if diceRoll == userEntry:
            print('Correct')
            sys.exit()

        if diceRoll != userEntry:
            print('Wrong, try again')
            print('The number generated was ' + str(diceRoll))
            continue

r = random.randint(1, 6)
outcome = randomNumber(r)
```

I want the program to ask the user the random number again if the user guessed wrong, but with a new number.

Comment: @TalhaIsrar there's absolutely not need for recursion here...

Comment: Seeing as this is in a while-true, recursion will be a bad solution and likely exhaust the call stack. In your function though, it seems you just want to generate the random number **inside the loop** thereby having a fresh random number every iteration.

Comment: the marked duplicate is about something else.. the question is about resetting the guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset `diceRoll` if the guess was wrong.

```
import random, sys

def randomNumber(diceRoll):

    while True:
        print('Pick a number 1 to 6')
        userEntry = int(input())

        if diceRoll == userEntry:
            print('Correct')
            sys.exit()

        if diceRoll != userEntry:
            print('Wrong, try again')
            print('The number generated was ' + str(diceRoll))
            diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6)
            continue

r = random.randint(1, 6)
outcome = randomNumber(r)
```

Comment: why use this line     while True: as it will always be true

Comment: because it loops as long as the guess is wrong, if its correct the program will close because of `sys.exit()`

Comment: Thank you, I only started learning 3 days ago. Sorry if this was a stupid question. it worked perfectly.

Comment: @TalhaIsrar please dont delete your comments, otherwise the comment section becomes confusing..

Comment: @Holloway96 there are no stupid questions (just badly formulated ones, which yours was not)

Comment: my ansver was wrong so i thought that i would cause trouble for others